# Number of representatives from states to from a comittee?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Among the three representatives to a conference from each of the fifty states, either none, one, or two of the representatives will be chosen for a large special committee. How many ways can this be done? The states are distinct and so are the representatives.

I'm stumped on this problem, please let me know if my reasoning is incorrect. Assume there are three representatives A,B,C from each state. There are 7 possibilities:

1. No reps are chosen for the committee
2. A goes
3. B goes
4. C goes
5. A and B go
6. A and C go
7. B and C go

So I reasoned that there are $7^{50}$ possibilities in total. Am I correct?

Edit: The answer ended up being correct. Thank you everyone!

Comment: I've thought about it for a bit and can't think of any reason this isn't correct.  Seems sound.  But there are people much sharper than I am that will hopefully speak up. (For item 1, did you mean No reps go to the committee?)

Comment: Yes, for (1) I meant the representatives aren't chosen for the committee

Comment: looks correct :)

Comment: It is right. The $7$ can be obtained in a somewhat simpler way. Of the $2^3$ possibilities for any state, only $1$ is forbidden.

Comment: The problem is hopelessly vague. What is a "**large** special committee"? Your $7^{50}$ committees range in size from $0$ to $100$ members. I don't believe that a committee with no members can be considered "large" and I have serious doubts about committees with one or even two members. Drop "large" from the statement and your solution is right, if an "empty committee" is allowed; or subtract $1$ from your answer if a committee must have at least one member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer to allow this question to be marked answered:

Yes, your result is correct, and you could derive the number $7$ of possibilities for each state by taking all $2^3=8$ possible subsets of the three candidates and subtracting the forbidden case where all three candidates are chosen.